# Upload profile picture to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile, outlook, lync

If I upload a picture to my user profile in SharePoint Online, will that picture sync to my Outlook and Lync also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your outlook is configured with the same user profile of the SharePoint online then it will be synced automatically.

The same will be applicable for Lync also.
So **Yes** if both your profile is configured with your SharePoint online account then it will be synced.